# Can I use one LM386 amplifier to drive 2 speakers(no stereo needed)?

Tags: lm386

Can I connect 2 speakers to the same output of the LM386 audio amplifier?

Comment: Sure. As long as the combined impedance is still within the specifications.

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet shows that an LM386 works well driving an 8 ohm speaker to 0.5W when powered from 9V. With a 12V supply or when a 4 ohm speaker or two 8 ohm speakers are in parallel then the total output power is almost the same but the IC heats up much more. If you connect two 4 ohm speakers in series then their total power will be the same as with one 8 ohm speaker.

Comment: just to clafify, that's a "yes" you can have sound in two different places by doing this, but it won't make it louder.